# Ip camera application

Tags: ios, camera, ip, onvif, psia

Please suggest me how to develop an iPhone/Android based application which can show live streaming from IP camera?

Is it possible to develop with simple HTTP programming?

If it is possible,is the HTTP API specific to the manufacturer of IP cam? 
What does these ONVIF and PSIA really define?

Does it mean if a IP cam follows ONVIF is the same app works with any other IP cam which adheres to ONVIF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ONVIF defines a standardized interface to send commands to an IP camera. It also endorses a behaviour of the camera through its tester, so yes, you can expect that if you interoperate with a camera then  you'll probabibly interoperate also with other ones.

The ONVIF specification  can be found [here](http://www.onvif.org/Documents/Specifications.aspx).

Finally, let's say that HTTP programming is in general not enough. You'll have to deal with a SOAP-defined protocol, and coding it by hand is, imho, crazy: never write a parser by yourself! (unless you really know what you're doing). Thus you'll need to make use of gsoap or visual studio or any other framework that generates encoding and decoding for you.